# lib/lib64 folder renamed in red hat linux. Anyway to fix it?

Tags: linux, redhat

We have a linux based server and the lib/lib64 folders were renamed (lib64 -> lib and lib -> lib2). The guy who did it already knows how stupid it was, but it's really screwed things up for the rest of us because now we can't use any functions, or log in as root to fix the problem.

Any ideas? We're hoping that we could boot from a red hat installation cd/DVD/usb, and run the commands that we need from there without overriding the actual OS thats already installed (it would take quite a while to get it back to where we are now) but I dunno if that's possible in our current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's definitely one way to do it. Boot from an installation disk and select rescue mode. Then mount the system's root filesystem and put the folders back.

Answer (score 4):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/mv /lib /lib3
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/mv /lib /lib64
mv /lib3 /lib
```

The main problem is that mv doesn't work because it can't find the loader,
but you can run the loader directly if you know its path.

Answer (score 0):

Boot off of any Linux distro's Live CD/DVD or flash drive, then open the file manager. From there you can click to mount the internal drive, navigate to the right folders and rename them.

This is Linux, a simple mistake like this is nothing to get excited about, just relax and it'll work out.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has busybox on it:

```
busybox mv /lib /lib64
busybox mv /lib2 /lib
```

I had the same problem, but renaming the folders to `/lib64` and `/lib` with busybox bailed me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can still invoke the `mv` command in the following way:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /lib64.bak /bin/mv /lib /lib64
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /lib64.bak /bin/mv /lib2 /lib
```

Comment: hope it could help someone if not lost connection

Comment: Can you please add some more explanation on why the command you give is solving the issue?

Comment: After renaming the lib64, the command like 'cp', 'mv', 'ln' and so on would become unusablie and show the log '-bash: /bin/mv: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory'.  The command I give manually specify the library path of 'ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'  for invoking the cp command.

Comment: In order to just rename the folders back to the names I would instead use mv. I have edited the answer and also included the names as per the original question.